# Reducedness assumption on $X/S$ in Sernesi's Deformations of Algebraic Schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory

I have a question about the proof of a result from
Edoardo Sernesi's [Deformations of Algebraic Schemes](https://%20https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-30615-3):

> **Theorem 1.1.10.** Let $X \to S$ be a morphism of finite type of
> algebraic schemes and $\mathcal{I}$ a coherent locally free sheaf
> on $X$. Assume that $X$ is reduced and $S$-smooth on a
> dense open subset. Then there is a canonical identification

$$ \text{Ex}(X/S, \mathcal{I}) = 
\text{Ext}^1_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\Omega^1_{X/S}, \mathcal{I}) $$

> which to the isomorphism class of an extension of $X/S$:

$$ \mathcal{E}: 0 \to \mathcal{I} \to \mathcal{O}_{X
'} \to 
\mathcal{O}_{X
} \to 0 $$

> associates the isomorphism class of the relative conormal sequence
> of $X \subset X
> '$:

$$ c_{\mathcal{E}}: 0 \to \mathcal{I} \xrightarrow{\delta}
(\Omega^1_{X'/S}) \vert _X \to \Omega^1_{X/S} \to 0   $$

> (which is exact also on the left).

> **Proof.** Suppose given an extension $\mathcal{E}$.
> Since $\mathcal{I}$ is locally free and $X$ is *reduced* in
> order to show that $ c_{\mathcal{E}} $ is exact on the left it
> suffices to prove that $\text{ker}(\delta)$ is *torsion*,
> equivalently that $ c_{\mathcal{E}} $ is exact at every general
> closed point x of any irreducible component
> of $X$. [...]

I do not understand the interplay of torsion sheaves with reducedness
of $X$ to show that $\text{ker}(\delta)$ is zero. Assume we manage
to show as the rest of the proof does that $\text{ker}(\delta)$ is torsion.
Since $\mathcal{I}$ is locally
free, we have a local problem: Assume $A$ is reduced Noetherian
ring and $M \subset A^n$ a torsion module, i.e.
$M \otimes_A \text{Frac}(A)=0$ where $\text{Frac}(A)$ is obtained
by localization of $A$ at all regular elements. Note that we did not assume $X$ resp. $A$ to be integral domain.

The author does not give the definition of a torsion sheaf/module he is working with, therefore I assume he works with the usual one: a module $M$ over a ring $A$ is torsion, if every element $m \in M$ is torsion, and $m$ torsion means that there exists a *regular* element $a \in A$ with $a \cdot m=0$. If Sernesi works with this definition, I do not see why it is necessary to assume $X$ resp $A$ to be reduced. On the other hand, there is a notion of annihilator

$$\text{Ann}(m)= \{a \in A \ \vert \ a \cdot m =0 \}.  $$

Note that the annihilator is allowed to contain non-regular elements, i.e. zero divisors in $A$. And the question is if the torsion modules in Sernesi book's consist of elements annihilated by a *regular* element or arbitrary non-zero elements of $A$. If the former is the case, I do not see where we need reducedness of $X$ resp. $A$. If Sernesi in contrast works with the latter definition of torsion module/sheaf, then I do not see how to conclude from $M \subset A$ torsion, that $M=0$.

Therefore the question becomes why to show $M=0$ the reducedness of $A$ is obligatory and where it is used? In global terms: Where in the proof the reducedness of $X$ resp. $A$ becomes important to show that the torsion sheaf $\text{ker}(\delta)$ must be even zero?